# Cannot Access Object Within Dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, indexing, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am having problems getting into an NSDictionary within another NSDictionary. I've been trying to access the text in the nodeContent key in the 0th index of the key nodeChildArray,"Number of Patrons Using Facility: 163". Here is the array.

```
{
nodeAttributeArray =     (
            {
        attributeName = class;
        nodeContent = style1;
    }
);
nodeChildArray =     (
            {
        nodeContent = "Number of Patrons Using Facility: 163";
        nodeName = text;
    },
            {
        nodeName = br;
    },
            {
        nodeContent = "
        Room Occupancy: 210 ";
        nodeName = text;
    },
            {
        nodeName = br;
    },
            {
        nodeContent = "
        Current Wait: 0 minutes ";
        nodeName = text;
    }
);
nodeName = p;
}
```

I have tried different variations of the following:

```
//I Parse some HTML using Xpath before this
NSArray *tutorialsNodes = [tutorialsParser    
searchWithXPathQuery:tutorialsXpathQueryString];

NSDictionary*dict=[tutorialsNodes objectAtIndex:0];
NSDictionary*dict2=[[dict objectForKey:@"nodeChildArray"]objectAtIndex:0];
```

So it should be returning both keys in the index but it keeps returning null. I'd really appreciate some help. Thanks!

Comment: so `dict` is not nil and `dict2` is nil?

Comment: That's correct, dict is not nil but dict 2 is nil. I'm not sure what's going on. yunas' answer below does not seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

MainResultDictionary => which contains your response

you should code

```
NSArray *dictsArr = [MainResultDictionary objectForkey:@"nodeChildArray"];
NSdictionary *dict = [dictsArr objectAtIndex:0];
[dict objectForkey:@"nodeContent"];
```

Comment: I appreciate it, but it's still not working, the result is (null)

Comment: why does it not work ? How do you get the result ? Can you share the code  ?

Comment: It turns out that the NSArray 'tutorialNodes' is a TFHippleElement, not an array. The code was returning null because dict is behaving more like a string...there is no key @"nodeChildArray".  To fix it, I had to use a different HTML parser, not Hipple